# MySQL won't update if content is changed

Tags: php, mysql, select

I got a PHP and MySQL problem, when I update the headline I got no problem. But when updating while having changed the content it won't update at all.

Any idea to what's going wrong.

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE about SET headline='$headline' WHERE content='$content'") 
or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM about ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $id = $row['id'];
   $headline = $row['headline'];
   $content = $row['content'];

   header("location: ../");
}
```

I'm coding in PHP and using and MySQL server.

I would prefer a solution that only calls the database once when updating.

Comment: when and how are you changing the 'content'-Field?

Comment: I have a form with a text input field and a textarea field, I would like them to be updated both in use of the submit button.

Answer (score 3):

When using an UPDATE statement, the WHERE clause is used to specify the record(s) to update. In the following case, where you've modified both the headline and content:

```
UPDATE about SET headline='$headline' WHERE content='$content'
```

The above query attempts to update the headline field where the content field equals the new content. There won't be any rows where the existing content matches the new content.

You'd have to do something similar to:

```
UPDATE about SET headline='$headline', content='$new_content' WHERE content='$old_content'
```

However, you should generally be selecting a record by an identifier, not a content field.

```
UPDATE about SET headline='$headline', content='$new_content' WHERE id = $id
```

If you update using a field like content, you may accidentally update all rows that have the same content, instead of just the row that you're trying to update. Using a unique identifier allows you to update only the specified row.

You could store the identifier in the session (on the server side).

Comment: how would you keep the old content while getting the new content

Comment: and BTW, you should escape $content. (see [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) )

Comment: You could place the content into a hidden text.

Comment: or having an ID column as primary key in your table *about* and using it to identify the row to update

Comment: @KasperNiemann, you could store the old value in the session, but it looks like you have an id field, so I would use that in the WHERE clause instead. I've added another paragraph to the end of my answer with why you should be using an identifier. Definitely don't use a hidden form field, especially if you are using it in your WHERE clause, since it allows the user to modify any record at will.